# Черный день и черный ход

Tags: этимология

"Черный день" — понятно. Черным всегда называли что-то плохое, а вот почему "черный ход"? Ничего плохого в нем нет, это просто вспомогательный вход в здание.

Answer (score 3):

Черный ход обычно скрыт от глаз посторонних, недоступен дня них. А чернота и темнота издавна ассоциируются с сокрытием, утаиванием (ср. "темнить", "черный рынок").

Answer (score 3):

Странно,я вроде довольно развернутый ответ в теме писал... Обидно. 
Ладно, попробую повторить, хотя бы кратко.

"Черный" означает не только плохое, а еще и всякое не парадное, служебное, вспомогательное.
Сравните: черновик, чернорабочий и проч. А еще есть всякие "баньки по черному", "черные избы" (и то и другое - без специального дымохода), черная металлургия (занимающаяся белыми по цвету металлами) и проч.

Кстати, не удивлюсь, если окажется, что популярности (не возникновением, ибо известно с давних времен) это выражение обязано Петербургу, где основной подъезд назывался и называется парадным, а вот ход со двора - для **черни** - надо было как-то обозначить...